# AWS Data Pipeline won't activate due to errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to activate a pipeline that I created in CloudFormation. However I get the following error, both from the CLI and also from the web interface:

> Pipeline definition has errors: Cannot activate a pipeline with errors.

However, if I export/re-import the pipeline, it says there are no errors:

```bash
$ aws datapipeline get-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id df-REDACTED > def.json
$ aws datapipeline put-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id df-REDACTED --pipeline-definition file://def.json
{
    "validationErrors": [],
    "errored": false,
    "validationWarnings": [
        {
            "id": "Default",
            "warnings": [
                "'pipelineLogUri'is missing. It is recommended to set this value on Default object for better troubleshooting."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
$ aws datapipeline activate-pipeline --pipeline-id df-REDACTED
A client error (InvalidRequestException) occurred when calling the ActivatePipeline operation: Pipeline definition has errors: Cannot activate a pipeline with errors
```

Creating a new pipeline with the same definition works as expected. However, since the pipeline is managed by CloudFormation, I don't know how to force it to re-create. I could commit a script change to delete the pipeline and then another one to create it again, but having to do something like that in production seems poor form.

A redacted copy of the pipeline definition (def.json) is available here: https://gist.github.com/corruptmem/26b866e31f9c85b4ce95d53f7d12f0a7

Comment: Can you paste your def.json? also what is the location of your file def.json?

Comment: I've attached a redacted def.json to the bottom of my post. The location is the working directory of the shell, which is my home directory. The pipeline definition is importing correctly, because I can see any changes I make visible in the web console.

Comment: Ok you will have to specify a log url in the json file where all the pipeline logs will be written, Are you planning to use a S3 bucket for logs?

Comment: The pipelineLogUri missing is a warning not an error. The pipeline should work without it, and indeed if I create another pipeline and put this definition into it, it works fine. But for completeness, I've just tried updating it with a log URI, so now no warnings appear, but it still didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into aws console
2. Navigate to data pipelines
3. Click on the troubled pipeline-id
4. Click `edit pipeline` button
5. Click `save` button
6. At the bottom pane, there are warnings and errors.
7. You'll see the error reported
   in my case it was:

> removal of component emractivity is not allowed

Note: this error is caused by trying to change the name of the emractivity.
It appears that is not allowed.

8. Fix whatever is causing the error in the definition
9. put updated pipeline definition via cli

`aws datapipeline put-pipeline-definition --pipeline-id df-86753098675309 --pipeline-definition file://path_to_your_file.txt`

Note: Perhaps you had the same issue where you changed the name of the emr activity.  This would explain it working on creating a new pipeline.